# Solving $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3})+\sqrt{n}$ using master method

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

How can I use the master's method in order to solve the recurrence formula $T(n)=3T(\frac{n}{3})+\sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Taking $n=3^k$ we have
$$T(n) =3 T(n/3) + \sqrt{n} =3^2T\left(\frac{n}{3^2}\right) +3\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}+ \sqrt{n} =\\ =3^3T\left(\frac{n}{3^3}\right) +3^2\sqrt{\frac{n}{3^2}}+3\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}+ \sqrt{n} = \cdots=\\
=3^kT\left(\frac{n}{3^k}\right)+3^{k-1}\sqrt{\frac{n}{3^{k-1}}}+\cdots +3\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}+ \sqrt{n} =\\
=3^kT(1)+\sqrt{n}\left( (\sqrt{3})^{k-1}+\cdots + \sqrt{3} +1\right) =\\
= 3^kT(1)+\sqrt{n}\frac{1-(\sqrt{3})^{k}}{1-\sqrt{3}}=\\
=\sqrt{n}T(1)+\sqrt{n}\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{1-\sqrt{3}} \in O(n)
$$

Comment: Thank you @zkutch for this answer, but how can we express it in terms of Θ or O notations?

Comment: Of course, but before you should finish sum in right side - it is geometrical progression - can you do it?

Comment: Here, a = 3, b=3, d = ½, and f(n) = √n , by comparing  n^(log_b a)=n^(log_3 3)= n^1 ≠f(n)

Comment: @Rako. Finished it up to big-$O$.

Comment: Looks like you dropped the 3 in front of T(n/3)

Comment: @Bobby Durrett. Of course I missed it and solve for $T(n/3) + \sqrt{n}$. I'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! @zkutch

Comment: Welcome @Rako. You can estimate it if/when you find it helpful. Feel free to ask any time if you need anything more.

Comment: Could you explain why the last step is $ O(n) $ ?

Comment: In last fraction, when we pull out $\sqrt{n}$, we have $\sqrt{n} \cdot   \sqrt{n}=n$.